# Change cursor when dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, cursor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing Mouse Cursor for HTML5 Drag Drop Files (GMail Drag Drop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459838/changing-mouse-cursor-for-html5-drag-drop-files-gmail-drag-drop)

I'm developing drag-and-drop extension for Google Chrome.

Selected text on the page can be dropped by user on specific areas implemented with dives and added to DOM.
When the text is dragged on such area and not dropped yet the cursor style should be changed.
The cursor for these areas is changed in document `dragstart` event with jQuery:

```
 $(".dropArea").css("cursor", "help");
```

This solution does not work.
Could anyone help to find the right solution for this issue?

Updated:

Example http://jsfiddle.net/mYpXQ/2/

Comment: You need to provide more code. Build the broken example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Added the link in question